# C++ const& binding to temporary object

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
 class Abc
 {
 public:
     Abc() { std::cout << " ABC::ABC\n"; }
     Abc& doIT() { std::cout << " Abc::doIT\n"; return *this; }
     ~Abc() { std::cout << " ABC::~ABC\n"; }
 };
```

Usage:

```
const Abc& ap = Abc().doIT(); //After this line ap references garbage
```

My question is why temp Abc destroyed and not binded to ap ?

Answer (score 6):

Lifetime extension only happens when you bind a reference to a prvalue *directly*.
In your case, the type of the expression `Abc().doIT()` is `Abc&` (an lvalue reference), not `Abc`.
This is not a prvalue, so lifetime extension does not apply.